# How to remove categories from json files?

Tags: python, json, list

I have a large 9million characters json file where information is located. with hundreds of item like this (see below)

```
"\u2605 Shadow Daggers | Damascus Steel (Well-Worn)":{
   "steam":{
      "last_90d":87.15,
      "last_30d":92.14,
      "last_7d":95.88,
      "last_24h":0
   },
   "bitskins":{
      "price":"80.35",
      "instant_sale_price":"32.14"
   },
   "lootfarm":95.59,
   "csgotm":"null",
   "csmoney":{
      "price":109.97
   },
   "skinport":{
      "suggested_price":71.78,
      "steam_price":0,
      "instant_price":0,
      "starting_at":null
   },
   "csgotrader":{
      "price":97.92
   },
   "csgoempire":61.59,
   "swapgg":95.47,
   "csgoexo":98.3,
   "buff163":{
      "starting_at":{
         "price":75.09
      },
      "highest_order":{
         "price":65.28
      }
   }
},
"\u2605 Shadow Daggers | Doppler (Factory New)":{
   "steam":{
      "last_90d":167.17,
      "last_30d":171.5,
      "last_7d":177.03,
      "last_24h":185.34
   },
   "bitskins":{
      "price":"155.74",
      "instant_sale_price":"62.3"
   },
   "lootfarm":185.92,
   "csgotm":"135.825",
   "csmoney":{
      "price":178.89,
      "doppler":{
         "Phase 2":193.58,
         "Phase 4":216.46,
         "Black Pearl":322.49,
         "Phase 1":191.44,
         "Sapphire":571.21,
         "Phase 3":178.89,
         "Ruby":463.07,
         "(Factory New)":0
      }
   },
   "skinport":{
      "suggested_price":541.92,
      "steam_price":0,
      "instant_price":0,
      "starting_at":123.76
   },
   "csgotrader":{
      "price":185.34,
      "doppler":{
         "Phase 2":171.84,
         "Phase 4":192.15,
         "Black Pearl":286.27,
         "Phase 1":169.94,
         "Sapphire":507.06,
         "Phase 3":158.8,
         "Ruby":411.07,
         "(Factory New)":0.0
      }
   },
   "csgoempire":113.99,
   "swapgg":175.39,
   "csgoexo":186.0,
   "buff163":{
      "starting_at":{
         "price":130.1,
         "doppler":{
            "Sapphire":385.85,
            "Ruby":310.91,
            "Black Pearl":222.19,
            "Emerald":"null",
            "Phase 1":130.1,
            "Phase 2":141.44,
            "Phase 3":130.25,
            "Phase 4":139.29
         }
      },
      "highest_order":{
         "price":127.34,
         "doppler":{
            "Sapphire":372.36,
            "Ruby":283.49,
            "Black Pearl":201.35,
            "Emerald":"null",
            "Phase 1":127.49,
            "Phase 2":128.87,
            "Phase 3":127.34,
            "Phase 4":134.85
         }
      }
   }
},
```

Im trying to make the file smaller by removing the useless categories such as steam, bitskins, lootfarm and others so only buff163 remains. Whats the best way of doing that? Oh also I'm doing this in python

Comment: Use `json.load()` to read the file into a dictionary. Loop through the dictionary elements, removing the categories you don't need. Then use `json.dump()` to rewrite the file.

Comment: Please read this to learn about json encoding/decoding: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
[json[key]["buff163"] for key in [*json.keys()]]
```